Problem installing curl on Ubuntu 24.04
I'm having trouble installing curl on Ubuntu 24.04. And most of the apps I use require it.
I run sudo apt install curl but I get the following error:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
curl : Depends: libcurl4t64 (= 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.2) but 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.3 is to be 
installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Output of apt policy curl libcurl4t64:
curl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.2
  Version table:
     8.5.0-2ubuntu10.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/main amd64 Packages
     8.5.0-2ubuntu10.1 500
        500 https://uk.mirrors.clouvider.net/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 Packages
     8.5.0-2ubuntu10 500
        500 https://uk.mirrors.clouvider.net/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Packages
libcurl4t64:
  Installed: 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.3
  Candidate: 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.3
  Version table:
 *** 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.5.0-2ubuntu10.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/main amd64 Packages
     8.5.0-2ubuntu10.1 500
        500 https://uk.mirrors.clouvider.net/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 Packages
     8.5.0-2ubuntu10 500
        500 https://uk.mirrors.clouvider.net/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Packages


The version of libcurl4t64 installed on your system is not from a software source currently attached to your system. This usually means that you installed software from a ppa and then removed the ppa without purging the software that was installed from it. Leading to a mess like this.  If I saw this on my system, I would use synaptic package manager and force install the version of the package from security.ubuntu.com But other orphaned packages may cause other issues.

@mook765
@steeldriver
My system is up to date. I have both issued apt update and apt upgrade.

@OrganicMarble But this is a fresh install of 24.04. I haven't messed with the system.

@OrganicMarble I got it fixed by following your suggestion. I force installed the appropriate version. Thanks.

Looks like the repository is/was messed up, see libcurl4t64 packages on launchpad, looks like an official version. See also curl packages on launchpad, a curl version 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.3 also exists.
